# Intuitive meaning behind f' = 0 implies inseparability

Tags: field-theory

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, and let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $K[x] - K$.  We know $f' = 0$ implies that $f$ is not separable. A proof that works is that if it were separable then we could write it in distinct linear factors over an algebraic closure, and substituting a root of $f$ in $f'$ gives a nonzero answer, hence $f'$ could not have been zero.

But I don't intuitively see why $f' = 0$ implies inseparability.

Comment: Inseparability as a whole is not the most intuitive thing. I think that proof is not too unintuitive - you already know the connection between multiple roots and derivatives from, say, an earlier calculus or real analysis class, so all you have to check here is that that still works over general fields.

Comment: Perhaps you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An argument which makes it bit more intuitive for me is that if $f' = 0$ then $f = g(x^p)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$. So when we look in an algebraic closure, we find that if $g(x)$ has $(x-a)$ as a linear factor, then $f$ has $(x - a^{1/p})^p$ in its factorization, hence not separable.